# Grouping and processing groups inside plpgsql functions

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

I need to perform a sophisticated group processing, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049647/selecting-positive-aggregate-value-and-ignoring-negative-in-postgres-sql). I get some rows from a complex query, the row set looks like this:

```
key val
-------
foo 1
foo 2
foo 3
bar 10
bar 15
baz 22
baz 44
...
```

And here is a pseudocode I want to implement in plpgsql:

```
result = new array()
group = new array()
current_key = null
for (record in (select * from superComplexQuery())) {
    if (current_key == null) {
        current_key = record.key
    }
    if (current_key != record.key) {
        result.add(processRows(group))
        group.clear()
        current_user = record.key
    }
    group.add(record)
}
if (group.size() > 0) {
    result.add(processRows(group))
}
return result
```

I.e., we must process 3 "foo" rows, then 2 "bar" rows, then 2 "baz rows" etc. And result of each processRows is added to resulting collection.

Maybe I should use another approach, but I don't know what it must be.

EDIT: processRows should output a record. Thus, the output of the whole procedure will be a set of rows, where each row is a result of processRows(group). One example of such calculation is given in first sentence of this question: [Selecting positive aggregate value and ignoring negative in Postgres SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049647/selecting-positive-aggregate-value-and-ignoring-negative-in-postgres-sql) , i.e. the calculation involves some iteration and aggregation with some complex rules.

Comment: Can you explain what you need `processRows` to do? It's quite likely you can accomplish this with GROUP BY if we know more about what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

The right approach was to use [User-Defined Aggregates](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/xaggr.html)

I.e. I successfully implemented my own aggregate function and the code looks like

```
select my_complex_aggregation((input_field_1, input_field_2, input_field_3)) 
from my_table
group by key
```