# Cancelled amount and a corresponding entry - Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have the payment table:

[image]

There could be erroneous entries when a payment was made by mistake - see row 5 and then, this payment gets cancelled out - see row 6. I cannot figure out the query where I don't only cancel the negative amounts but also the corresponding pair. Here is the desired outcome:

[image]

You could also see the cases when several wrong payments were made and then, I need to cancel out all payments which if summed up give the cancelled amount.

[image]

The desired outcome:

[image]

I found [Remove Rows That Sum Zero For A Given Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27829960/remove-rows-that-sum-zero-for-a-given-key), [Selecting positive aggregate value and ignoring negative in Postgres SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049647/selecting-positive-aggregate-value-and-ignoring-negative-in-postgres-sql) and https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/select-all-negative-values-that-have-a-positive-value but it is not exactly what I need

I already don't mind cases like case 2. At least, find a reliable way to exclude those like 5;-5.

Comment: What is the primary key of your table payment ? How to identify one row among all the rows with the same id and the same amount  in the table payment ?

Comment: Good point. There is a column index which is basically an incremental sequence

Answer (score 1):

**you can try this for deleting the rows from the table :**

```
WITH RECURSIVE cancel_list (id, total_cancel, sum_cancel, index_to_cancel) AS
(  SELECT p.id, abs(p.amount), 0, array[p.index]
     FROM payment_table AS p
    WHERE p.amount < 0
      AND p.id = id_to_check_and_cancel -- this condition can be suppressed in order to go through the full table payment
  UNION ALL
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (l.id) l.id, l.total_cancel, l.sum_cancel + p.amount, l.index_to_cancel || p.index
     FROM cancel_list AS l
    INNER JOIN payment_table AS p
       ON p.id = l.id
    WHERE l.sum_cancel + p.amount <= l.total_cancel
      AND NOT l.index_to_cancel @> array[p.index]  -- this condition is to avoid loops
)     
DELETE FROM payment_table AS p
 USING (SELECT DISTINCT ON (c.id) c.id, unnest(c.index_to_cancel) AS index_to_cancel
          FROM cancel_list AS c
         ORDER BY c.id, array_length(c.index_to_cancel, 1) DESC
       ) AS c
 WHERE p.index = c.index_to_cancel;
```

**you can try this for just querying the table without the hidden rows :**

```
WITH RECURSIVE cancel_list (id, total_cancel, sum_cancel, index_to_cancel) AS
(  SELECT p.id, abs(p.amount), 0, array[p.index]
     FROM payment_table AS p
    WHERE p.amount < 0
      AND p.id = id_to_check_and_cancel -- this condition can be suppressed in order to go through the full table payment
  UNION ALL
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (l.id) l.id, l.total_cancel, l.sum_cancel + p.amount, l.index_to_cancel || p.index
     FROM cancel_list AS l
    INNER JOIN payment_table AS p
       ON p.id = l.id
    WHERE l.sum_cancel + p.amount <= l.total_cancel
      AND NOT l.index_to_cancel @> array[p.index]  -- this condition is to avoid loops
)     
SELECT *
  FROM payment_table AS p
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ON (c.id) c.id, c.index_to_cancel
               FROM cancel_list AS c
              ORDER BY c.id, array_length(c.index_to_cancel, 1) DESC
            ) AS c
    ON c.index_to_cancel @> array[p.index]
 WHERE c.index_to_cancel IS NULL ;
```

Comment: Thank you, Edouard! Just one question, as per my understanding, the query will actually delete from the table. Is it possible just to hide those pairs from the result query?

Comment: just updated the answer in order to just hide the rows

Comment: It looks like it will run for quite some time. Edouard, an apology for being picky and if I drop the 2nd use case (-15), can the query be simplified?

Comment: Updates, so, I got the case when I have +20005 and -20005, so instead of removing +20005 and -20005, it removed all proceeding rows to -20005 which if summed up are equal to 20000

Comment: You have to express the rule or the sorting you want to select the right rows among all the rows with the same id with a positive amount and which you want to hide : is it the list of rows sorted by index descendent ? is it the list of rows sorted by amount descendent ? or anything else ? I cannot decide for you.

Comment: Edourad, I proposed to close the question because it seems to be easy to complete with the code than with SQL. Thank you for your help, very much appreciated

Comment: Thanks to vote on the answer if it has been useful.